# Manage wireless network profiles in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I mananage my wireless network profiles in Windows 8? In Windows 7 there used to be an option in the Network and Sharing Center, but in Windows 8 it's no longer there.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, it is not necessary to use a third party tool.

Comment: Removing this functionality is inexplicable to me. Every time the guest Wifi password changes at work, I now have to delete and re-add the wifi profile. Grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I have managed to find is a third party program from The Windows Club.

[Here is a link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-profile-manager-windows-8)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use a third party tool, the one from the Windows Club is just a wrapper for the netsh command line tool.

[Here is a full list of command you can use to change the priority etc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanShowProfiles).